# docker-compose `restart: always` randomly not working

Tags: debian, docker, docker-compose

I administer a few Debian servers with Docker CE installed and docker-compose orchestrating several services (roughly 20 containers per machine)..

Every single service is configured with `restart: always` in docker-compose. However, there are random services (usually 1-2 per machine) that shut down correct but do not restart during a host reboot. This behaviour is completely random. Sometimes all services start, sometimes one single service from a docker-compose.yml file does not restart.

Following is an example where Traefik did shut down correctly but did not come up:

1. Service configured to restart automatically:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:1.7
    restart: always
    command: --web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
    networks:
      - web
```

2. Exit code is 128

```
$ docker-compose ps
         Name                Command        State     Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------
traefik_reverse-proxy_1   /traefik --web   Exit 128
```

3. Logs show that the service has shut down correctly but there are no signs of activity since then:

```
$ docker-compose logs --tail 6 -t
Attaching to traefik_reverse-proxy_1
reverse-proxy_1  | 2022-01-21T14:05:28.042399112Z time="2022-01-21T14:05:28Z" level=info msg="Stopping server gracefully"
reverse-proxy_1  | 2022-01-21T14:05:28.042450915Z time="2022-01-21T14:05:28Z" level=debug msg="Waiting 10s seconds before killing connections on entrypoint http..."
reverse-proxy_1  | 2022-01-21T14:05:28.042463326Z time="2022-01-21T14:05:28Z" level=debug msg="Waiting 10s seconds before killing connections on entrypoint api..."
reverse-proxy_1  | 2022-01-21T14:05:28.053256515Z time="2022-01-21T14:05:28Z" level=debug msg="Entrypoint api closed"
reverse-proxy_1  | 2022-01-21T14:05:28.053283046Z time="2022-01-21T14:05:28Z" level=debug msg="Entrypoint http closed"
reverse-proxy_1  | 2022-01-21T14:05:28.059721498Z time="2022-01-21T14:05:28Z" level=info msg="Shutting down"
```

4. Server uptime corresponds with the shutdown message:

```
$ uptime
 11:21:31 up 29 days, 20:15,  1 user,  load average: 0.46, 0.43, 0.44
```

5. My docker-version is the following:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
```

Let's not focus on Traefik alone because it is completely random which container does not start and when.

Comment: I'm having the same issue....debian 11, exit code 128 on containers. Did you ever get to the bottom of this? Worked fine on CentOS

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I reinstalled the particular VPS a little later (probably a different version of all of the components: OS, Docker, docker-compose) and currently it works. Albeit, it does bother me that I don't know what caused the problem.